# Check an Admin account only using Javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

Could anyone suggest a way to use Javascript to check whether or not the logged in user to a SharePoint site is Admin?

We need to hide some of the SharePoint's MasterPage ContentPlaceHolders if the logged in user is not an administrator.

Answer (score 4):

### How to determine if User is Site Admin via CSOM

[User.IsSiteAdmin property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.user.issiteadmin.aspx) specifies whether the user is a site collection administrator.

> Limitations:  this property is not available in SharePoint 2010 CSOM

```
function isCurrentUserSiteAdmin(OnSuccess,OnError)
{
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
    context.load(user);

    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
          var isSiteAdmin = user.get_isSiteAdmin();  
          OnSuccess(isSiteAdmin);           
        },
        OnError
    );
}

//Usage
isCurrentUserSiteAdmin(function(isAdmin){
        console.log(isAdmin);
    },function(sender,args){
        console.log('An error occured: ' + args.get_message());
    }
);
```

For SharePoint 2010

```
function isCurrentUserSiteAdmin(OnSuccess,OnError)
{
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = context.get_web().get_siteUserInfoList();
    var userItem = list.getItemById(_spPageContextInfo.userId);

    context.load(userItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
          var isSiteAdmin = userItem.get_item('IsSiteAdmin');  
          OnSuccess(isSiteAdmin);           
        },
        OnError
    );


}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SP 2010 or SP 2013, you can use SharePoint Javascript client object model code to check if user has admin permissions or not. This is done by using `Web.DoesUserHavePermissions`. If a user is admin he/she will have `manageWeb` permissions. Here is a sample code:

```
var context;
var web;
var isAdmin = false;
function CheckUserPermissions() {
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = context.get_web();
    context.load(web, 'EffectiveBasePermissions');
    context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);
}
function onSuccess() {
    if (web.get_effectiveBasePermissions().has(SP.PermissionKind.manageWeb)) {
        isAdmin = true;
    }
}
function onFailure(sender, args) {
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + 'n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can edit the page layouts or the master page you could make use of the `SPSecurityTrimmedControl`, a guide is found here -> http://www.infowisesolutions.com/blog/Comments.aspx?ArticleId=28

The main idea is the wrap the placeholders or other elements with this tag, and in the tag set the minimum permissions for the content to be rendered